# Android custom spinner with right icon, left arrow and custom shape for stroke

Tags: android-layout, android, android-styles

I am working on an android app for which I have been provided with design images. All the UI elements need to be custom designed.

Following are the images for the EditText view and Spinner that I have to implement

EditText
[image: EditText]

Spinner
[image]

I have implemented the EditText using a custom shape and leftDrawable for the icon, however I am not sure how to do the same for the spinner, because as I see it, it requires a custom shape for the background and stroke on focus, left icon and the right dropdown arrow.

I tried using a list layer to combined these three drawables, however it did not work, everything just comes on top of each other. and I am not able to provide the padding like the EditText.

In short, I want that the spinner should look like the EditText along with the right dropdown arrow.

Comment: For that you can use a Relative/LinearLayout and put an ImageView and Spinner (Horizontally) and then set background to the layout.